# Bash: Redirecting file descriptors

Tags: bash, redirect, file-descriptor

I am hoping someone can explain a phenomenon. As the title indicates I am learning about redirection of file descriptors. Along the way I have come across a question surrounding the use of the redirect symbol, specifically when setting permanent redirection. I have noticed that in certain cases it does not seem to matter whether I use `<` or `>`. For example, working with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Setting file descriptor 3 to redirect  to STDIN
exec 3<&0

#Setting STDIN to read from input file
exec 0<inputFile


while read var
do
    echo "$var"

done

#Setting STDIN to read from file descriptor 3 which is redirected to the default STDIN
exec 0<&3

read -p "Enter a word:" word

echo "$word"
```

To my astonishment it does not seem to matter if I use `>` or `<` in the statements `exec 3<&0` or `exec 0<&3`. In either of these statements it seems that if I swap out the redirect symbols, I still get the exact same result. It seems obvious to me that making the same types of changes to the line:

```
exec 0<inputFile
```

vs.

```
exec 0>inputFile
```

does not produce the same results, because redirecting STDIN to a file is not the same thing as redirecting a file to STDIN.

So my questions are:

1. `<` vs `>`:

   ```
   # Why aren't there any differences between these two statements?
   exec 3<&0
   exec 3>&0
   ```
2. `3<&0` vs `0<&3`:

   ```
   # Why is there a difference between these two statements?
   exec 3<&0
   exec 0<&3
   ```

This type of redirection is hard enough for me to wrap my head around and keep straight without these types inconsistencies. Any explanation(s) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've mildly edited your post to reflect both questions you asked. Feel free to rollback or edit further if you don't like my changes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When *duplicating* file descriptors, it doesn't matter, [`dup2`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) is called, no matter if you use `<` or `>`.

The same occurs when *closing* file descriptors. You can use `n>&-` or `n<&-`.

---

> However why then is `0<&3` not the same thing as `3<&0`?

That's explained in the `dup2` spec I linked:

> ```
> int dup2(int fildes, int fildes2);
> ```
>
> The dup2() function shall fail if:
>
> [EBADF]
>
> The *fildes* argument is not a valid open file descriptor or the argument *fildes2* is negative or greater than or equal to {OPEN_MAX}.

In the case of `exec 0<&3`, Bash calls `dup2(3,0)` and indeed receives `EBADF` error (since we're in the case *fildes*=3 which is not a valid open file descriptor at that time). You can easily check that with `strace`:

```
$ strace -e dup2 bash -c 'exec 0>&3'
dup2(3, 0)                              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
dup2(10, 0)                             = 0
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Perhaps some of my confusion comes from my book describing this as "redirecting" file descriptors, when it should be thought of as "duplicating" them? However why then is '0<&3' not the same thing as '3<&0'?

Comment: Ok, I think I completely understand now. Although in your edit you say that "fildes=3 which is not a valid open file descriptor at that time". This is not the true for the last exec statment in the script. At that point the 3 file descriptor has been open? However, given what you have laid out here, I think the best way to think of all this is in terms of duplicating rather than redirecting. If I think of it that way, it seems that all the confusion goes away. "0<&3" is not the same as "3<&0" because duplicating 3 is not the same as duplicating 0. Thank you much for bring me this clarity.

Comment: @Dr.Tautology: exactly!